# WebScraping with SED

Tags: linux, bash, sed, web-scraping

Let me preface this by saying I know that web scraping in sed is a dumb idea when there are so many better tools. I tried telling my teacher this, but he's adamant about using sed and awk.

My goal is to scrape a twitter page and return all the tweets. Using this code:

```
sed -n '/<p class=\"TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text\" lang=\"en\" data-aria-label-part=\"0\">/,/<\/p>/p' $targ | sed 's/<[^>]\+>/ /g;s/^[ \t]*//;/^$/d'
```

[On this URL](https://twitter.com/i/streams/category/4) I have so far been fruitless in getting exactly what I want.

Here is the code surrounding a tweet:

`<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">Where is our universe headed?  Answer to it&#39;s death, not to worry <a href="/PaulMattSutter" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" data-mentioned-user-id="556263627" ><s>@</s><b>PaulMattSutter</b></a> explains. <a href="https://t.co/ig8KtQzwOI" rel="nofollow" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://oak.ctx.ly/r/42bnj" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://oak.ctx.ly/r/42bnj" ><span class="tco-ellipsis"></span><span class="invisible">http://</span><span class="js-display-url">oak.ctx.ly/r/42bnj</span><span class="invisible"></span><span class="tco-ellipsis"><span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span></a> <a href="https://t.co/kOy4jLCogk" class="twitter-timeline-link u-hidden" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/kOy4jLCogk</a></p>`

Now, I want to only grab content from the page between `<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">` and its corresponding `</p>` and then I want to filter that so that all tags inbetween (both open and closed) are removed, so that it looks like this:

`Where is our universe headed?  Answer to it&#39;s death, not to worry @PaulMattSutter explains. http://oak.ctx.ly/r/42bnj pic.twitter.com/kOy4jLCogk`

Comment: It looks like you're passing a filename argument to sed in both your commands in the pipeline. You only want to do that in the first one. The second should use the pipe input and not the original file.

Comment: Sorry, it was a messy copy/paste

Comment: This is the strongest evidence I've seen for the need for a `rube-goldberg` tag :)

Comment: @chicks when I told him I was just going to call python to do it for me, he got very angry and said he would take off half my grade. This is ridiculous because this is just  very small section of the overall project. I'd never heard of Rube Goldberg, but from what I just Googled, I think you're spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 sed -n '/<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">.*<\/p>/{s/<[^>]*>//g;p}' file
```

Output:

```
        You’ve never seen Pluto like this! @NASANewHorizons returns sharpest views yet! Take a look: http://go.nasa.gov/1NxLViz  pic.twitter.com/iK4OJKeLUE
        The world is filled with those who do nothing yet criticize. I love this @rickygervais motto: Go create! pic.twitter.com/m7zB8ucclT
        Can you see me waving? How to spot #Mars in the night sky: https://youtu.be/hv8hVvJlcJQ  https://amp.twimg.com/v/9b945202-5a89-4efa-80ab-514a0c17a965 …
        We knew the first high-res images of Pluto would be good, but we didn't expect THIS good: http://ow.ly/Vvrvm  pic.twitter.com/r8ZX4Z5tVt
        Toddler wears the most precious 'Monsters, Inc.' costume this world has ever seen http://on.mash.to/1HLrcMk  pic.twitter.com/2PyuDW9yms
        Are you on your way to your @TMobile store, @ATT customers?! GO!! #UncarrierUnwrapped http://t-mo.co/1SzhOfb  pic.twitter.com/0vNJbD2J4k
        1 year ago today, @USNavy @ussanchorage recovered Orion in Pacific ocean after successful flight. pic.twitter.com/DKW00LzlC3
        How Fallout 4 mastermind Todd Howard builds his epic dream worlds http://wrd.cm/1IILf8N  pic.twitter.com/WUV98e6U62
        23-year-old’s design collaboration tool Figma launches with $14M to fight Adobe http://tcrn.ch/1YPW8Pw  pic.twitter.com/wVrZbfgBOc
        Here’s a list of questions investors will ask themselves after you pitch a company to them. http://kpcb.cc/b466b5b  pic.twitter.com/zOJDOrq0na
        Blow your mind with this--ENJOY! (And check the SWEET video too)! http://www.nasa.gov/feature/new-horizons-returns-first-best-images-of-pluto … #PlutoFlyby pic.t
        Human gene editing is OK, but no designer babies—for now, summit concludes: http://ow.ly/VscSg  #GeneEditSummit pic.twitter.com/UW6DKtQX4h
        NASA releases the highest resolution images ever taken of Pluto http://www.theverge.com/2015/12/4/9851162/nasa-new-horizons-pluto-photo-new-high-resolution?utm_campai
        A drone that finds you a parking space and then hovers in it to stop anyone else taking it first.
        The ubiquity of guns poses a much greater threat to Americans than terrorism http://bit.ly/1lbvPoQ  By @Horganism pic.twitter.com/pdxvVqGS59
        Scientist disinvited from speaking at conference because of her pregnancy http://ow.ly/Vvyam  pic.twitter.com/FUAjaycIom
        Samsung agrees to pay Apple $548 million in settlement http://engt.co/1jEN28t  pic.twitter.com/3DmmccJUgW
        World's first in-human gene-editing treatment will tackle hemophilia http://www.engadget.com/2015/12/03/worlds-first-in-human-CRISPR-hemophilia/ … pic.twitte
        Where is our universe headed?  Answer to it's death, not to worry @PaulMattSutter explains. http://oak.ctx.ly/r/42bnj  pic.twitter.com/kOy4jLCogk
        New Horizons just sent back the sharpest images possible of Pluto's surface. Drink it in http://www.wired.com/2015/12/new-horizons-just-sent-its-highest-res-image
        Get people to do what you want with these 11 clever psychological tricks: http://lifehac.kr/GZaSWhN  pic.twitter.com/5rhWlVL9t0
```

Comment: Excellent! It appears I was very close. I appreciate the help. This community is so much better than the tutors my university offers